# c# Regex- split string by multiple delimiters but not inside quotes

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to parse an expression in c#. 
The expression can contain variables from a variable table, so I need to replace every variable name with it's value. In order to do it, i'm splitting the string using:

```
string[] split = Regex.Split(expression, @"([ !<>\b==\b+-/*])");
```

However, this becomes bad when a string contains string literals. for example:

`"\"number-\" + num "` (comes from `Console.print("number-" + num)`)

should be split to `{"\"number-\"", "num"}`,
instead of what it does currently: `{"\"number", "-\"", "num"}`.

I found ways to split everything outside quotes with a single delimiter char, but I tried replacing the delimiter with my delimiter list, and it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your delimiter list contains `==`, you cannot put it into a character class, you need an alternation group. Besides, `\b` inside `[...]` does not match a word boundary, but a backspace char. A `-` in between `+` and `/` in the character class creates a range. So, the regex you are using is a mess. Besides, could you please fix the verbatim string literal so that we could try and help you? Does it look like `@" ""number-"" + num "`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks I didn't know you can't use \b inside a character class. I also edited the question. How would I be able to get the result I want? Or where can I get detailed explanation on c# regex? Google search found me what I currently use, and you say its wrong.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/ZcII18/2. It may be too verbose, but I really do not know what you are doing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The code you sent doesn't work the way I need- it does exactly what my previous code does. The result is still {"number, -, ", +, num}. Also in the regex tester you sent, the "number-" gets matched.

Comment: Yes, it is not only matched, it is *captured*, so that the `Regex.Split()` could ouput the match in the resulting array. Unless you clarify with a better example and perhaps explicit requirements, I do not think I (or anyone else) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took me a while to get into your problem, but I think I have a solution.
I suggest to use two match options, one with a positive lookbehind and one with a positive lookahead. I've adapted some of @Wiktor's operator matches, but stripped of the rare ones.

`(?<=\"[ ]+)(-|&&|\+\+|[&*%/|^!=+<>-]?=|[|+&<>%!~^/.*-])|(-|&&|\+\+|[&*%/|^!=+<>-]?=|[|+&<>%!~^/.*-])(?=[ ]+\")`

Here is the verbatim string: `@"(?<=\""[ ]+)(-|&&|\+\+|[&*%/|^!=+<>-]?=|[| +&<>%!~^/.*-])|(-|&&|\+\+|[&*%/|^!=+<>-]?=|[|+&<>%!~^/.*-])(?=[ ]+\"")";`

Here is the testable [sample](https://regex101.com/r/4Ik9DK/1). (It's not perfect since regex101 does not allow quantifiers in a lookahead/behind - read below).

You showed us only one example, so I have made up some more. For complex  scenarios this solution will loop holes. But his should answer the OP. The regex can split samples like this successfully:

```
"number-" + num  
"number-" += num  
"-free-" == bear  
boom += "*freezer*"  
great + "stuff"  
boom + "-freezer-" + "wild"
```

The operators are also included. You may want to keep them. If you don't want them us this instead:

`@"(?<=\""[ ]+)(?:-|&&|\+\+|[&*%/|^!=+<>-]?=|[|+&<>%!~^/.*-])|(?:-|&&|\+\+|[&*%/|^!=+<>-] ?=|[|+&<>%!~^/.*-])(?=[ ]+\"")";`

One important thing here is, the [lookahead/behind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) do not work properly in most regex engines if you put quantifiers in it. Look, there is only one single space. If you want more, the the .NET framework RegEx classes allows you.

Take care.